# POST http://localhost:8080/api/users/login 404 (Not Found) in Vue.js Axios

Tags: javascript, post, vue.js, authentication, vuejs2

In console i have error POST http://localhost:8080/api/users/login 404 (Not Found). This is my login component. There is any error. I am install axios. Also this component am registered in root component but without success.

```
  <script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data () {
          return {
            username: '',
            password: ''
          }
        },
        methods: {
            login() {
            axios.post('/api/users/login', {
                username: this.username,
                password: this.password
                })
                .then((response) => {
                     localStorage.setItem('id_token', response.data.token);
                     this.$router.push('/dashboard')
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                })
            }
        }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: does the POST route work in other contexts like Postman?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `8080` for your vue app. Can you check your ports?

Comment: Yes my port is 8080.
port: 8080, // can be overwritten by process.env.PORT, if port is in use, a free one will be determined